# Suave SQl Provider DatabaseProvider has already been given a value

Tags: .net, f#, suave

I am currently going through the Suave Music store tutorial and have come to the database portion, where they instruct you to build a SQL connection like this:

```
type Sql = 
SqlDataProvider< "Server (LocalDb)\\v11.0;Database=SuaveMusicStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true", 
    DatabaseVendor=Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER >
```

However, I get the error "The static parameter 'DatabaseVendor' has already been given a value". I've tried looking at the [SQL Provider Basics](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/general.html) page, which suggests a different initialization method but have had no luck using it either. Has anyone else experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this for my connection string and it works for me, for Initial Catalog put the name of your database

```
let [<Literal>] ConnectionString = """Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=NavcareDB_backup;Integrated Security=True;"""
type Sql = SqlDataProvider<ConnectionString = ConnectionString,
                           DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
                           UseOptionTypes = true>
```